# Spacing between top-level bullet points in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have a list with bullet points in an email I am composing in Outlook 2010, for example:

- A top level bullet
  - 1
  - 2
- B top level bullet
  - 5
  - 6
  - 7
  - 8
- C top level bullet
  - 3
  - 4

It starts off looking like the above, with no line spacing at all.  I can find a number of ways of playing with paragraph settings to get this, with line spacing between every line:

- A top level bullet

- 1

- 2

- B top level bullet

- 5

- 6

- 7

- 8

- C top level bullet

- 3

- 4

But what I want is this (ie space between only the top-level bullets A/B/C/etc, without space between the indented ones):

- A top level bullet

- 1

- 2

- B top level bullet

- 5

- 6

- 7

- 8

- C top level bullet

- 3

- 4

Is that possible with line spacing settings or do I have to keep entering extra blank lines?

(apologies, the layout of the bullets I tried to write are a bit off from the description! What I'm aiming for is:

- A top level heading
  ---- indent bullet
  ---- indent bullet
  [vertical space]
- B top level heading
  ---- indent bullet
  ---- indent bullet
  ---- indent bullet
  ---- indent bullet
  [vertical space]
- C top level heading
  ---- indent bullet
  ---- indent bullet
  etc

That'll teach me for trying to be clever and drawing the proper splodges!)

Thanks,
Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid it cannot be realized using the built-in options. You may have to manually inserting extra blanks or using the workaround below:

1. Let's say you only need to use a two-level bullets, create a customized multilevel list as follows:
   (For the third level, set the formatting as none.)
   [image]
2. Use the steps below to type your list:

1). Press ***, Space** to insert the first level bullet, type "A top level heading".

2). press **Enter, Tab** to insert the second level bullet, type "1", press Enter, type "2".

3). Press **Enter, Tab** to insert the third level, press **Space** so that this line won't be removed when you press Enter, Press Enter.

4) Press **Shift+Tab** twice to go back to the first level, type "B top level heading", refer to the steps above to type the other text.

[image]

Comment: Hi Yuki, thanks for the information.  Just knowing there's no built-in way to do it is the main thing I needed so I don't spend ages looking :-)  The problem with your workaround is that it only works if I have bullet lists with two levels, as it puts a gap as the third level, rather than before the first level, to give that effect.

I can probably get the same desired effect as a workaround just by doing Shift-Enter (to get a bullet line with no bullet) and then another Space and Enter (to continue with the bullets) which is perhaps simpler but alas still not automatic with spacing ;-)